# Improper integral of unbounded function over bounded interval

Tags: calculus, proof-writing, improper-integrals

I'm asked to prove one of the properties of improper integrals for unbounded functions over bounded integrals. The problem is stated at follows:

---

Let f,g:[0,a] $ \to \mathbb R$ be two functions s.t
$$0 \le f(x) \le g(x) \forall x\in[0,a]$$  and $$\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0^+}
g(x) =  \infty $$
Then, if $\int_0^a g(x)$ exists and $\int_\epsilon^a f(x)$ exists $\forall \epsilon > 0$

Prove that $\int_0^a f(x)$ exists

---

Well my first doubt is about the functions I reckon they should be defined as functions over (0,a] and not [0,a], or they wouldn't approach infinity as the x goes to zero, right? Anyway it  could be just a mistake.

I was thinking of using $\int_0^a g(x)$ as an upper bound for $\int_0^a f(x)$ if it exists

Then $$\int_0^a f(x) = \int_0^\epsilon f(x) + \int_\epsilon^a f(x)$$
then by taking the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$ the $ \int_0^\epsilon f(x) $ part goes to zero and we have that the other expression exists and is bounded above by $\int_0^a g(x)$, however when I try to write it formally I am not sure of how to proceed, any help would be appreciated

Comment: If $\int_0^a f$ exists then should $\int_\epsilon^a f$ exist...(for$0 \le\epsilon \le a$

Comment: sorry I made a mistrake it was $\int_0^a g(x)$ exists and $\int_0^a f(x)$ exists $\forall \epsilon > 0$

Answer (score 1):

To show that $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0+} \int_{\epsilon}^{a} f(x)dx$ exists it is enough to show that $\lim_{\epsilon, \delta \to 0+ } \int_{\epsilon}^{\delta} f(x)dx=0$. To show this use the fact that $\lim_{\epsilon, \delta \to 0+ } \int_{\epsilon}^{\delta} g(x)dx=0$ and use Sequeeze Theorem.